# Access UserPoolId from aws-cdk Stack outside of aws-cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I deployed an AWS Cognito UserPool via `aws-cdk` as `CognitoStack`.

Now, I want to automate testing of a GraphQL API that uses said AWS Cognito UserPool for authentication.

**How can I programmatically get the `UserPoolId` required for authentication from `CogntioStack`?**

My `CognitoStack` is:

```js
export class CognitoStack extends Stack {
  public readonly userPool: UserPool;

  constructor(scope: App, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    this.userPool = new UserPool(this, 'UserPool', {
      signInAliases: {
        email: true,
        phone: false,
        username: false,
        preferredUsername: false,
      },
      autoVerify: {
        phone: false,
        email: false,
      },
      selfSignUpEnabled: true,
    });

    this.userPool.addClient('web', {
      authFlows: {
        refreshToken: true,
        userSrp: true,
      },
    });

    new CfnOutput(this, 'UserPoolId', {
      value: this.userPool.userPoolId,
    })
  }
}
```

When I do `cdk deploy CognitoStack` I get:

```sh
Outputs:
CognitoStack.UserPoolId = eu-central-1_xafasds
CognitoStack.ExportsOutputRefUserPool6BA7E5F296FD7236 = eu-central-1_xasdfdd
```

However, when I inspect `cdk.out/CognitoStack.template.json` (which I easily could `require` in my test), there is no `eu-central-1_xasdfdd` appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way I've found so far is use the --outputs-file flag when running the deploy command, and then I have a json file with all fields I need.

```
cdk deploy CognitoStack --outputs-file outputs.json
```